# Raising an exception from a third party API

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
context 'given an invalid build name' do
  let(:config_file) { ('login.yml') }
  let(:client) { double(JenkinsApi::Client) }
  let(:logger_mock) { double("logger").as_null_object }
  let(:exception) { double(JenkinsApi::Exceptions::NotFound) }

  before do
    allow(YAML)
      .to receive(:load_file)
      .with('login.yml')
      .and_return(config_file)
    allow(JenkinsApi::Client)
      .to receive(:new).with(config_file).and_return(client) 
    allow(client).to receive_message_chain(:job, :status) {'build'}
    allow(client.job).to receive(JenkinsApi::Exceptions::NotFound).and_return(exception)
  end

  it 'should throw NotFound error' do
    expect{client.job.status('bad_build')}.to raise_error
  end
```

For testing, I want the Jenkins API to raise JenkinsApi::Exceptions::NotFound. I don't want to ping an actual server for the test, but to use mocking to raise the exception. I have tried numerous variations and am unable to successfully call it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Failure/Error: allow(client.job).to  
  receive(JenkinsApi::Exceptions::NotFound).and_return(exception)

NoMethodError:
   undefined method `to_sym' for JenkinsApi::Exceptions::NotFound:Class
   Did you mean?  to_s
```

This is the current error I am receiving. I also have been getting errors about not actually raising the exception.

Comment: What error / wrong behavior did you get with the code you posted ?

Comment: Errors added to main, thanks for that.... forgot to put them!

Comment: In the test you showed, you're not testing your code, but constructing a mock and testing that. Show your code that you're trying to test.